# Android program runtime error

Tags: android, android-widget

What am i doing wrong below in the code the code compiles but when installed gives an error

```
  package com.app.newapp;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class NewappActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      ImageView.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
      Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              String pwd="pd";
              EditText  et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
              if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(pwd))
              {
                  ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);
                  ImageView.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
              }

          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: What error does it give? Please include a stacktrace / logcat output.

Comment: com.app.newapp closed...

Comment: That really doesn't help. As I said in my previous comment, you'll need to include a stacktrace or logcat output if you want anyone to help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below things

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
ImageView imagvw1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Imageviewname);
imagvw1.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal to get an error.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main); 
**ImageView.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);**
```

What about the image view? Do you have any instance of this? Or is null reference?

Answer (score 0):

You did two mistakes
1) initialize image view
2) set the visibility to the imageview objects only.

Try with the following code

```
 import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class NewappActivity  extends Activity {
      ImageView iv= null;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);
      iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              String pwd="pd";
              EditText  et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
              if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(pwd))
              {

                  iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }

          }
      });
  }
```